# Is it possible for Scala to automatically pass parameters in the following example?

Tags: scala

I'm trying to define a clean interface for clients to use my library. Some sample client code is below.

```
for (security <- allSecurities) {
  val askLast = ask
}
```

The problem is I would like "ask" to automatically be passed "security". My attempt at doing this in the parent class is as follows

```
 var lastSecurity = ""  
  private val lastAsk = new HashMap[...]
  def allSecurities = for {
    security <- lastTrade.keySet.toList
  } yield {
    lastSecurity = security
    security
  }

  def ask = lastAsk(lastSecurity).price
```

Unfortunately it doesn't quite work as I envisaged since in the client lastSecurity has the same value throughout the entire loop instead of being dynamically updated.. So basically I'm trying to allow clients to do

```
val askLast = ask
```

instead of

```
val askLast = ask(security)
```

Can I do this in Scala?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get what you want with a lazy "view" of the sequence,

```
  var lastSecurity: Int = _
  val securities = Seq(1, 2).view.map { a => 
    lastSecurity = a
    a
  }

  for (s <- securities) {
    println("%d %d".format(s, lastSecurity))
  }
```

prints

```
1 1
2 2
```

The key idea here is that with a lazy view, the `map` is not evaluated immediately, but only as elements are needed by the for loop.

---

Here's another approach. I'm not recommending this as good code, but it does demonstrate the flexibility of Scala,

```
  var lastSecurity: Int = _

  class SecurityWrapper(s: Seq[Int]) {
    def foreach(f: Int => Unit) {
      s.foreach { a =>
        lastSecurity = a
        f(a)
      }
    }
  }

  for (security <- new SecurityWrapper(Seq(1, 2))) {
    println("%d %d".format(security, lastSecurity))
  }
```

The class `SecurityWrapper` contains a custom `foreach` method. In each iteration through the loop, it writes to the `lastSecurity` variable. Scala's `for` comprehension sugar will automatically use `SecurityWrapper.foreach` without any extra work on our part.

Answer (score 0):

why not create a list of prices in parent class and use it in client ?

```
def myfunc = for(security <- allSecurities) yield {       
  lastAsk(security).price
}
```

As for your original intent I guess the nearest that you can get is:

```
var askLast = ask _
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's something close that avoids clients needing to pass an argument to ask. You could modify the `allSecurities` method to yield a tuple containing the security and the value that would be returned by the ask call, i.e.

```
def allSecurities = for {
  security <- lastTrade.keySet.toList
} yield {
  (security, lastAsk(security).price)
}
```

With this, clients could write

```
for((security,askLast)<-allSecurities){
  //to client things with askLast
}
```